# What is this operator overloading function overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I am looking through the CMBC source code and came across this code snippet:

```
void goto_symext::operator()(const goto_functionst &goto_functions)
{
  goto_functionst::function_mapt::const_iterator it=
    goto_functions.function_map.find(goto_functionst::entry_point());

  if(it==goto_functions.function_map.end())
    throw "the program has no entry point";

  const goto_programt &body=it->second.body;

  operator()(goto_functions, body);
}
```

I have never seen a `operator()(args)` syntax before and googling does not seem to yield anything.

Comment: It's overloading the function call operator. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_function_call_operator).

Comment: overloading a function call, wow that is a mouthful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the function call operator, which allows you to make function-like objects.

```
struct Functor {
    bool operator()(int a, int b = 3);
};

bool Functor::operator()(int a, int b /* = 3 */) {
    if ((a > (2 * b)) || (b > (2 * a))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// ...

Functor f;
bool b = f(5); // Calls f.operator()(5, 3).
bool c = f(3, 5);
```

It has the benefits that you can save state information in the function-like object's fields, and that if necessary, you can hide overloaded versions of the operator within the object instead of leaving them exposed.

```
class Functor {
    int compareTo;

    public:
        Functor(int cT);

        bool operator()(int a);
        bool operator()(char c);
};

Functor::Functor(int cT) : compareTo(cT) { }

bool Functor::operator()(int a) {
    if ((a > (2 * compareTo)) || (compareTo > (2 * a))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Functor::operator()(char c) { return false; }
```

It can be used to make it easier to write code that can accept any function instead of depending on function pointers.  [It works especially well when used in tandem with templates, in this regard.]

See [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

As answered in the comments, `/*return type*/ operator()(/*params*/)` is the syntax for overloading the `()` operator.

```
struct Foo { void operator()() { std::cout << "Hello, world!"; } };

Foo f;
f(); //Hello, world!
```